# Почему нельзя модифицировать захваченные по значению переменные в лямбде?

Tags: c++

Предположим у нас есть класс:

```
class Probe
{
public:
   Probe(){}
   Probe(const Probe &aData){}
   Probe(Probe &&aData){}
   void setA(int aA) {a = aA;}
private:
   int a = 0;
};


int main()
{
    Probe vProbe;
    auto foo = [vProbe]() {vProbe.setA(5); };
    foo();
    return 0; 
}
```

Вот этот код компилироваться не будет так как пишется что vProbe это константа, но если передавать по ссылке то компилируется без проблем. Так почему такое возможно? Если передается копия объекта и по идее нет никакого основания делать эту копию константой.

Comment: Если вы захватываете копию и хотите ее модифицировать, необходимо указать спецификатор `mutable`: `[vProbe]() mutable { vProbe.setA(5); }`

Answer (score 9):

Потому что лямбда - это просто синтаксический сахар для класса с оператором круглые скобки. И если ничего не делать, то он помечен как const функция. А то, что передано в квадратных скобках будет "переменными этого класса". А если функция класса помечена const, то модифицировать переменные класса нельзя. Если добавить mutable, то const не добавляется.

Почему было сделано именно так? Видимо для оптимизаций.

**UPD**
Найдено оригинальное объяснение от Саттера - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3424.pdf

> This feature appears to have been added out of a concern that the user might not realize he got a copy,
> and in particular that since lambdas are copyable he might be changing a different lambda’s copy

То есть, "пользователь может не понимать, что это копия и модифицируя ее, он будет не понимать, что происходит".

**END OF UPD**

То есть, Ваша лямбда это

```
class __lambda_20_16
{
  public: 
  inline /*constexpr */ void operator()() const // ключевое!!!
  {
    vProbe.setA(5);
  }

  private: 
  Probe vProbe;
  public: 
  // inline __lambda_20_16 & operator=(__lambda_20_16 &&) = delete;
  __lambda_20_16(const Probe & _vProbe)
  : vProbe{_vProbe}
  {}

};
```

Есть чудесный сервис - https://cppinsights.io/ там можно посмотреть, как именно оно раскрывается. Правда с не компилируемым кодом оно не работает:)